# how can i send smtp mail with Command Prompt?

Tags: cmd, smtp

I try that in cmd `telnet mail.server.com 25` but i got this error Could not open connection to the host, on port 25: Connect failed I used different port but i got the same error

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port 25 is basically restricted these days to mail servers talking to teach others.  Clients wishing to submit mail for delivery should use port 587.

Comment: `telnet mail.hostingbay.net 587`
I have verified that this works.  Try it.  If you still get the error, then the problem is with your local machine or your network.  If you don't get the error then the problem is with your server.

Comment: one more quenstion..what i put in HELO value ?? as i read in some page i put my domain name where i find that ?  i am new at this dont judge me :)

Comment: The `HELO` value is the domain you're sending mail from.  It can be anything you like in theory, but a properly configured mail client will use this value to determine if it's prepared to let you send mail.  Wikipedia has a decent description of the protocol and an example session: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol